# Forces on group of electrons in electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, coulombs-law, dipole-moment

Short electrodynamics question:

If I have a small number of electrons in an external uniform electric field, would I be right in stating that we can view it as three forces at play, a coulomb force of repulsion between them, a force due to the external electric field on them individually and a torque on the group due to the fact that as a group they have an electric dipole moment and the external electric field produces a torque on them. Is this correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, partly correct. Not sure about the torque though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is correct, if a bit simplistic in outlook.

In this situation, you've got a set of $n$ particles at positions $\mathbf r_i$ which are subject to two separate forces,

- internal Coulomb interactions $\mathbf F_{ij} = \frac{q_iq_j}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}(\mathbf r_i-\mathbf r_j)/\|\mathbf r_i-\mathbf r_j\|^3$, and
- interactions with an external electric field, $\mathbf F_i=q_i\mathbf E(\mathbf r_i)$.

---

As with all systems of interacting particles, you can always define the centre of mass as $\mathbf R=\frac1M \sum_i m_i\mathbf r_i$, and it will evolve in time exclusively via the total external force on the system,
\begin{align}
M\ddot{\mathbf R}
&= \sum_i m_i \ddot{\mathbf r}_i
\\ &= \sum_i q_i \mathbf E(\mathbf r_i) + \sum_{i\neq j}\mathbf F_{ij}
\\ &= \sum_i q_i \mathbf E(\mathbf r_i),
\end{align}
since the $\mathbf F_{ij}$ cancel out pairwise. Here, *if* the external electric field is uniform, the total force reduces to 
$$
M\ddot{\mathbf R} = \left(\sum_i q_i\right) \mathbf E = Q \mathbf E,
$$
i.e. you can ignore the internal details of the particle configuration insofar as the centre-of-mass motion goes. If the field is not uniform, then this simplification ceases to hold.

---

Similarly, you can define the total angular momentum of the body, taken about the centre of mass, i.e. as $\mathbf L = \sum_i (\mathbf r_i-\mathbf R)\times m_i(\dot{\mathbf r}_i-\dot{\mathbf R})$, and it will only evolve through the total external torque. To see this, first take
\begin{align}
\dot{\mathbf L}
& = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \sum_i (\mathbf r_i-\mathbf R)\times m_i(\dot{\mathbf r}_i-\dot{\mathbf R})
\\ & = \sum_i (\mathbf r_i-\mathbf R)\times m_i(\ddot{\mathbf r}_i-\ddot{\mathbf R})
\\ & = 
\sum_i (\mathbf r_i-\mathbf R)\times \left[\mathbf F_i +\sum_{j\neq i} \mathbf F_{ij}\right]
-\sum_i (\mathbf r_i-\mathbf R)\times m_i\ddot{\mathbf R}
\\ & = 
\sum_i (\mathbf r_i-\mathbf R)\times q_i\mathbf E(\mathbf r_i)
,
\end{align}
where I've used the fact that $(\dot{\mathbf r}_i-\dot{\mathbf R})\times (\dot{\mathbf r}_i-\dot{\mathbf R})$ vanishes, and the second two terms also vanish:

- In the last term, the summation over $i$ only plays out on the position vectors, and this actually vanishes: $\sum_i m_i (\mathbf r_i-\mathbf R) =0$.
- Similarly, the internal forces also give a vanishing contribution, because the line of action is always along the relative separation. Thus,
  \begin{align}
  \sum_{i\neq j} (\mathbf r_i-\mathbf R)\times \mathbf F_{ij}
  & =
  \sum_{i\neq j} \frac{q_iq_j}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\mathbf r_i\times\frac{\mathbf r_i-\mathbf r_j}{\|\mathbf r_i-\mathbf r_j\|^3}
  -\mathbf R\times \sum_{i\neq j} \mathbf F_{ij}
  \\ & =
  \sum_{i\neq j} \frac{q_iq_j}{4\pi\varepsilon_0} \frac{\mathbf r_i\times(\mathbf r_i-\mathbf r_j)}{\|\mathbf r_i-\mathbf r_j\|^3}
  \\ & = 0,
  \end{align}
  since the direct terms vanish and the cross terms come in matching pairs that cancel out.

We have, then, that the total angular momentum changes according to the sum of the individual torques exerted about the centre of mass by the external field. Now, *if* the external field is uniform, then you can simplify this to
\begin{align}
\dot{\mathbf L}
& = 
\sum_i (\mathbf r_i-\mathbf R)\times q_i\mathbf E(\mathbf r_i)
\\ & = \left[\sum_i q_i(\mathbf r_i-\mathbf R)\right]\times \mathbf E
\\ & =\mathbf d\times \mathbf E
,
\end{align}
where $\mathbf d=\sum_i q_i(\mathbf r_i-\mathbf R)$ is the dipole moment of the system taken about the centre of mass (and which is independent of $\mathbf R$ if and only if the total system charge is zero); under the uniform-field assumption, then, the total torque is simply given by the torque exerted on the total dipole by the external field. If the field is not uniform, then you cannot do this simplification.

---

This is as far as the system-wide equations of motion go. In addition, you will have internal motion within the system of charges, which is described using body-fixed frames of reference which are too messy for this post, so I'm going to skip them. In general, you expect the internal dynamics to be affected by the external field, but if the field is uniform then this will probably drop out.